# Get distinct values from sqlAlchemy object

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have two models: Product and MBiopoint.
They are related through a many to many table named t_Dataset_Data. In Product table there is the attribute 'data' declared like this:

```
data = relationship(u'MBiopoint', secondary=t_Dataset_Data)
```

So when I query the Product table for a specific product like this:

```
prod = session.query(Product).filter_by(product_id=69).first()
```

i can now have access to all MBiopoint records that are associated with my product in the many to many table, through this code for example (to access the value of datastatus column of MBiopoint):

```
for pd in prod.data:
   print pd.datastatus
```

What I need now is to get the distinct values of 'datastatus' column of all data records associated with my product without using a for loop, something like this: `d = prod.data.datastatus.distinct()`

Do you have any idea?
Otherwise, I can I get the distinct values using the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Using the freenode Web IRC webchat, the user with the nickname 'agronholm' gave a solution for my problem. 
What he suggested was:

```
set(pd.datastatus for pd in prod.data)
```

or in a modern way:

```
{pd.datastatus for pd in prod.data}
```

That worked for me.